# Why doesn't Programmable Interval Timer show correct Time values when using Int 0x21 with service 0x2c

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

What i am trying to achieve here is to hook the Programmable Interval timer Interrupt (int 8) to display current time on the screen (video memory 0xb800) and then press a key to pause that timer and press the same key to resume that timer.

For the time being i just want to make the time Display on the screen and keep it running indefinitely (in a loop).

Below is my code, let me explain what I am doing and the problem I am facing, I have subroutine **DisplayUpdatedTime** which calls the **Int0x21** with service **0x2c** which returns hours in ch, minutes in cl and seconds dh, then save the values in Hour, Minutes and Seconds in Memory Variables and calls PrintByte. The **PrintByte** subroutine converts the bytes in al register to their corresponding ASCII and Print them on screen.

So The issue now I am facing is that when in call DisplayUpdatedTime in my Interrupt routine of int 8, The time when my Program is executed is shown but is never updated despite running a empty infinite loop. (see code to get the idea), but when I run the DisplayUpdatedTime Subroutine in loop than calling it in the Interrupt routine(int 8) it works fine and I get timer updated every second.

My Question why does my subroutine works fine when calling it in an Independent loop not when I call it in a Interrupt service?

```
DisplayUpdatedTime:
pusha
push es
push word 0xb800
pop es
sti ;enable interrupts just in case the function is called from another 
;interrupt
mov ah, 0x2c
int 0x21
xor ax,ax
mov al, ch ;place hours
mov byte [cs:Hours],al ; save the current hours
mov di,140
call PrintByte
add di,4
mov word [es:di],0x073A ;ASCII of Colon 0x3A
add di,2
mov al,cl ;place minutes
mov byte [cs:Minutes],al ; save the current Minutes
call PrintByte
add di,4
mov word [es:di],0x073A
add di,2
mov al,dh;place seconds
mov byte [cs:Seconds],al ; save the current Seconds
call PrintByte
pop es
popa
ret


;take argument in al to prints and prints at current location of di
PrintByte:
pusha 
push es
push word 0xb800
pop es
mov bl,10
div bl
mov dh, 0x07
;quotient in AL, Remainder in AH
add al, 0x30 ;adding hex 30 to convert to ascii
mov dl, al
mov word [es:di],dx
add di,2
add ah,0x30
mov dl, ah
mov word [es:di],dx
mov ax,0
pop es
popa
ret`


timmerInterrupt:
push ax

call DisplayUpdatedTime

mov al,0x20 ; send EOI to PIC
out 0x20,al
pop ax
iret
```

This works

```
start: 
l1:
    call DisplayUpdatedTime
jmp l1
```

This Doesn't works Why?

```
start: 

xor ax,ax
mov es,ax ; point to IVT base

cli                                       
mov word [es:8*4], timmerInterrupt ;hook int 8            
mov [es:8*4+2], cs                       
sti    

l1:
jmp l1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My Question why does my subroutine works fine when calling it in an Independent loop not when I call it in a Interrupt service?

Int 08h is called by the system clock approximately 18.2 times per second. Because this interrupt is called every 55 msec, a handler for it must execute as quickly as possible. Therefore it is not a good idea to do extensive work while in this interrupt handler.

It is entirely possible and very probable that DOS could be occupied when the int 08h is activated. If this happens and your replacement handler invokes a DOS function, you get what is called re-entrancy. But given that by design DOS is not re-entrant problems will eventually arise!

Your replacement code for int 08h also dismisses of much of the work that needs to be done here:

- Advancing the time-of-day indicator at 0040h:006Ch
- Providing automatic motor-off functionality for disks
- Calling the user hook interrupt vector 1Ch
- Acknowledging the interrupt
- ...

These are the reasons why **your program should hook the interrupt 1Ch** instead. It shares the same top priority than int 08h, but your interaction with it is much simpler.
The usual way to deal with this important handler is to merely set a flag that the main program can pick up for any processing that is required at a later time when all is save with regard to interrupts.

Below is an example of this:

```
; --------------------------------------- Code section
Start: 
    mov     [SaveInt1C + 2], cs          ; Completing the far pointer

    push    es
    push    0
    pop     es                           ; Point to IVT base
    mov     eax, [SaveInt1C]
    xchg    [es:1Ch*4], eax              ; Hook int 1Ch
    mov     [SaveInt1C], eax             ; Save vector so it can be restored!
    pop     es

MainLoop:
    cmp     byte [cs:TimerFlag], -1      ; Is flag set ?
    jne     NoTick
    not     byte [cs:TimerFlag]          ; Reset flag -1 -> 0
    call    DisplayUpdatedTime
NoTick:

    ... everything else in your program ...

    jmp     MainLoop

Quit:
    mov     eax, [SaveInt1C]
    push    0
    pop     ds                           ; Point to IVT base
    mov     [1Ch*4], eax                 ; Restore int 1Ch

    mov     ax, 4C00h                    ; DOS.Terminate
    int     21h

TimerInterrupt:
    mov     byte [cs:TimerFlag], -1      ; Set flag
    iret                                 ; Complete take-over
TimerFlag   db 0

; --------------------------------------- Data section
SaveInt1C          dw TimerInterrupt, 0
EnableTimerDisplay db -1
```

> ... and then press a key to pause that timer and press the same key to resume that timer.

Don't to try to squeeze this into the interrupt handler.
Next is what you can do from your main program loop:

- Test to see if a key is available

  ```
      mov     ah, 01h                  ; BIOS.TestKey
      int     16h                      ; -> AX ZF
  ```
- If yes, then fetch it

  ```
      jz      NoKey
      mov     ah, 00h                  ; BIOS.GetKey
      int     16h                      ; -> AX
  ```
- If it is the designated key e.g. <kbd>p</kbd> then toggle an enable bit

  ```
      or      al, 32                   ; LCase
      cmp     al, 'p'
      jne     NotMyKey
      not     byte [EnableTimerDisplay]
  ```
- Call *DisplayUpdatedTime* based on this enable bit

  ```
      cmp     byte [cs:TimerFlag], -1      ; Is flag set ?
      jne     NoTick
      not     byte [cs:TimerFlag]          ; Reset flag -1 -> 0
      cmp     byte [EnableTimerDisplay], -1
      jne     NoTick
      call    DisplayUpdatedTime
  NoTick:
  ```

---

Basically there are 2 ways to hook an interrupt:

- Take over completely by finishing your replacement code with `iret`
- Chain to the previous handler:

  - using `jmp far [...]` instead of `iret`
  - using `call far [...]` and still ending with `iret`

Chaining gives other pre-existing processes a chance to keep getting their work done. If we completely take over the handler then those processes are taken out of the loop.

Example 1 using late chaining to old handler:

```
; --------------------------------------- Code section
Start: 
    mov     [cs:SaveInt1C + 2], cs       ; Completing the far pointer

    push    es
    push    0
    pop     es                           ; Point to IVT base
    mov     eax, [cs:SaveInt1C]
    xchg    [es:1Ch*4], eax              ; Hook int 1Ch
    mov     [cs:SaveInt1C], eax          ; Save vector so it can be restored!
    pop     es

MainLoop:
    cmp     byte [cs:TimerFlag], -1      ; Is flag set ?
    jne     NoTick
    not     byte [cs:TimerFlag]          ; Reset flag -1 -> 0
    call    DisplayUpdatedTime
NoTick:

    ... everything else in your program ...

    jmp     MainLoop

Quit:
    mov     eax, [cs:SaveInt1C]
    push    0
    pop     ds                           ; Point to IVT base
    mov     [1Ch*4], eax                 ; Restore int 1Ch

    mov     ax, 4C00h                    ; DOS.Terminate
    int     21h

TimerInterrupt:
    mov     byte [cs:TimerFlag], -1      ; Set flag
    jmp far [cs:SaveInt1C]               ; Chaining to old handler
TimerFlag   db 0
SaveInt1C   dw TimerInterrupt, 0

; --------------------------------------- Data section
EnableTimerDisplay db -1
```

Example 2 using early chaining to old handler:

```
; --------------------------------------- Code section
Start: 
    mov     [cs:SaveInt1C + 2], cs       ; Completing the far pointer

    push    es
    push    0
    pop     es                           ; Point to IVT base
    mov     eax, [cs:SaveInt1C]
    xchg    [es:1Ch*4], eax              ; Hook int 1Ch
    mov     [cs:SaveInt1C], eax          ; Save vector so it can be restored!
    pop     es

MainLoop:
    cmp     byte [cs:TimerFlag], -1      ; Is flag set ?
    jne     NoTick
    not     byte [cs:TimerFlag]          ; Reset flag -1 -> 0
    call    DisplayUpdatedTime
NoTick:

    ... everything else in your program ...

    jmp     MainLoop

Quit:
    mov     eax, [cs:SaveInt1C]
    push    0
    pop     ds                           ; Point to IVT base
    mov     [1Ch*4], eax                 ; Restore int 1Ch

    mov     ax, 4C00h                    ; DOS.Terminate
    int     21h

TimerInterrupt:
    pushf
    call far [cs:SaveInt1C]              ; Chaining to old handler
    mov     byte [cs:TimerFlag], -1      ; Set flag
    iret
TimerFlag   db 0
SaveInt1C   dw TimerInterrupt, 0

; --------------------------------------- Data section
EnableTimerDisplay db -1
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for this excellent explanation!, but can you explain what does "re-entrant" means or point me to a source from where I can get more info

Comment: @Shehroz This [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)) does a good job explaining it. The first paragraph should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

The BIOS time is updated by the timer interrupt, so once you hook the timer interrupt the time doesn't get updated. Probably your interrupt handler and display routine are working perfectly, but the time returned by int 21h never changes. Hook interrupt 1ch instead; it is provided for exactly this purpose. (Alternatively, you can save the original handler for interrupt 8 and call it from your handler.)

Comment: Don't forget that most of the functions provided by DOS are not re-entrant, and can't be expected to work properly from inside an IRQ handler (unless you test a "currently in DOS" flag to make sure the IRQ didn't interrupt DOS).

Comment: @Brendan, thanks. I thought of that, but I don't think it's the problem because his main loop doesn't do anything. But I should have mentioned it in the answer anyway.

Comment: Thanks can you Elaborate more on this please "(Alternatively, you can save the original handler for interrupt 8 and call it from your handler.)"

Comment: @Shehroz I've elaborated on the topic of *call it from your handler* in my answer. See today's edit.